# Laravel eloquent model relationship utility method fails first time

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, contains

In a fresh installation of Laravel 8.20.1, I have created two models `Company` and `User` with a pivot table between to facilitate a many-to-many relationship. The pivot has a `role` attribute.

I can add a user to a company using:

```php
$company->users()->attach($user);
```

I've added a utility method `addUser` so that I can first check existence of the relationship to avoid duplication:

```php
public function addUser(User $user) {
    if($this->users->contains($user)) {
        // if the user already has a role, update it
        Log::info("User #{$user->id} present - updating");
        $this->users()->updateExistingPivot($user, ['role' => 'user'], true);
    } else {
        // if the user doesn't have a role, add it
        Log::info("User #{$user->id} not present - adding");
        $this->users()->attach($user, ['role' => 'user'], true);
    }
}
```

The first time I run this using a refreshed database, it should see that the user is not yet related to the company and run the `else` part of the switch to add a new user. Running this in Tinker, it appears to do this - and the logs show 'User #1 not present - adding' - but when I check for presence using `contains`, it returns false:

```php
$user = User::factory()->create();
$company = Company::factory()->create();

$company->addUser($user);
print_r($company->users->contains($user)); //false
```

I've tried logging the queries for this function, and I they look fine - one for checking existence of the user, a second for inserting the pivot.

Also, *I can see a pivot record for user #1 and company #1*, and if I then test this in Tinker, I get true:

```php
print_r(Company::find(1)->users->contains(User::find(1))); // true
```

It's almost as if the database is running async, which I know isn't the case in PHP. I'm using Sqlite v3.31.0.

The issue is definitely in my `addUser` method, as if I replace this call in Tinker with calling `attach` directly, it works.

I'm really keen to use this utility method (and others), because:

- I want to avoid multiple pivot records for the same company/user (without using compound indexes)
- I need several more utility methods such as `addAdmin`, `addOwner`, etc

Comment: Have you tried using the `syncWithoutDetaching()` method?

Comment: This does solve it, thank you! Still interested as to why my code doesn't work though.

Comment: Might be that `$company->users`, being a Collection, isn't updated on `attach()`. If you did `print_r($company->users()->get()->contains($user))` you might see `true`. Or, `$company->fresh()->users->contains($user)` (i.e. reloading the Model's relationship before trying to check `contains()`). Not sure how that would behave with Factory logic though...

Comment: Did you figure it out?